# OptaPlanner chained variables not considering other problem facts due to a hard constraint

Tags: java, optaplanner

I have a domain set up for chained variables and I'm trying to schedule multiple Tasks to a Shift, very similar to the Call Center example of assigning Calls to Agents. Each Task has a Delivery associated to it and each Delivery has ~7 tasks.

These Tasks are chained together because they are required to be in a certain order and certain tasks are collapsable. The problem is that I have a hard constraint stating that all Tasks on a Delivery must be within the same Shift because it wouldn't make sense for some Tasks on a Delivery to be on multiple Shifts. This constraint is causing Optaplanner to put all Tasks from multiple Deliveries onto 1 Shift and never consider other Shifts, which later down the line will break other hard constraints (ex. there's not enough time to have 10 Deliveries on 1 Shift).

I believe this is happening because during initialization, the first Task gets put onto a Shift and then the hard constraint prevents all other Tasks on a Delivery to try other Shifts since it will be breaking the hard constraint. Removing this constraint fixes this issue and Tasks consider multiple Shifts but now all Tasks on a Delivery are not together on the same Shift which will not work.

I'm not sure how else I could write this constraint or if using a weighted constraint would work either since this constraint must not be broken. I've considered using a custom move that uses a CompositeMove to move all Tasks on a Delivery to a new Shift in 1 Move but am struggling to implement this since I haven't found any resource online that uses CompositeMove with a chained variable.

I'm wondering what else I can try. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you're having this issue is that your data model actually allows a state that should not be allowed. (These extra tasks can be part of different shifts, even though in practice it must not be allowed to happen.) Once OptaPlanner gets you in that state, it will be hard - if not impossible - to get out.

The way I see it, you have several options:

- Write move filters that would prevent OptaPlanner from creating this wrong state. That said, move filters are overhead. Still, this is only a part of the solution; to help OptaPlanner actually improve your solution, you may also need to...
- Write custom moves instead of OptaPlanner's generic moves. It will be the job of these moves to never ever get the solution into the wrong state. These will be somewhat difficult to write; handling chaining is no fun.
- Preferrably though, you should change your data model so that this state is impossible. One idea comes to mind. You can have two levels of tasks - one that keeps the actual chain ("parent tasks"), and the other ("subtasks") that are just pointing to their parents; they don't form a chain, they just reference the parent. If the parent changes its position in the chain, the subtasks still point to the parent - they always "move together".

Changing the data model is the preferred way, because it is the only approach where you do not need to work around invalid states. Every time you need to filter moves or generate complex custom moves, you waste CPU time. If your data model makes certain situations impossible, you do not waste time preventing or fixing them.